# xcode interface builder - view sticks to the mouse

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, interface-builder

For some reason I cannot get drag and drop any view right now. I can drag, but then the view just sticks to the mouse - cannot drop!:D

Happens on Xcode 6.3 (6D570), OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 (14D136), MBP15 mid2010.

I've restarted Xcode several times - no change. I guess it's a bug in this update?

Comment: Please specify which object your are trying to drop ? are you using storyboard?

Comment: Storyboard, it was a UIImageView, however it was the same for every object I touched.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to select different file, select different xib or storyboard and then select the original storyboard and drag and drop there. I know, it's plain weird.